No ticks on the x-axis
Here is the graph that I've produced using Wolfram mathematica:
I can't see the ticks on the x-axis. I don't know the command for it. I already attempted many times but got failed.
Here is the code that I've tried
ParametricPlot[{Sin[t], t}, {t, -4*Pi, 4*Pi},
AspectRatio -> 1.5,
Ticks -> {Range[-7*(Pi/2), 7*(Pi/2), Pi/2]},
AxesLabel -> {"x-axis", "y-axis"}]


Welcome to Mathrmatica StackExchange! I suggest the first thing you should do in such cases is to look into the documentation, for example, for Ticks. You will then figure out thag you've turned them off. Write Ticks -> {Automatic, Range[...]} to get them back.

Got it!. I just learned this Wolfram mathematica a couple of days ago and already done a lot of readings . Thank you again @Domen
